# Junit import error при запуске тестов

Tags: java, junit, импорт

[image: Подключил все необходимое,но при запуске теста - еррор. Какой-то трабл с подключением Junit. Не пойму в чем дело.]
Подключил все необходимое,но при запуске теста - еррор. Какой-то трабл с подключением Junit. Не пойму в чем дело.

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;



public class MenusTest {
Menus menus = new Menus();
    @Test
    public void getArray() {

    }

    @Test
    public void setArray() {

    }

    @Test
    public void testAdd() {
        //given
        ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        numbers.add(10);
        numbers.add(20);
        //when
        menus.add(numbers);

        //then
        int a = numbers.get(0);
        int b = numbers.get(1);
        Assert.assertEquals(30,a);
        Assert.assertEquals(20,b);

    }

    @Test
    public void delete() {
    }

    @Test
    public void find() {
    }

    @Test
    public void findElementByIndex() {
    }

    @Test
    public void maxValue() {
    }

    @Test
    public void minValue() {
    }

    @Test
    public void averageElement() {
    }

    @Test
    public void startMenu() {
    }

    @Test
    public void arraySize() {
    }

    @Test
    public void printMainMenu() {
    }

    @Test
    public void getInteger() {
    }
}



Information:java: Errors occurred while compiling module 'Project'
Information:javac 9.0.1 was used to compile java sources
Information:09.01.2018 17:56 - Compilation completed with 17 errors and 0 warnings in 3s 182ms
C:\Users\Sanevski\Desktop\Project\src\Tests\MenusTest.java
Error:(5, 24) java: package org.junit does not exist
Error:(3, 1) java: package org.junit does not exist
Error:(10, 6) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Test
  location: class MenusTest
Error:(15, 6) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Test
  location: class MenusTest
Error:(20, 6) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Test
  location: class MenusTest
Error:(37, 6) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Test
  location: class MenusTest
Error:(41, 6) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Test
  location: class MenusTest
Error:(45, 6) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Test
  location: class MenusTest
Error:(49, 6) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Test
  location: class MenusTest
Error:(53, 6) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Test
  location: class MenusTest
Error:(57, 6) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Test
  location: class MenusTest
Error:(61, 6) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Test
  location: class MenusTest
Error:(65, 6) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Test
  location: class MenusTest
Error:(69, 6) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Test
  location: class MenusTest
Error:(73, 6) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Test
  location: class MenusTest
Error:(32, 9) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable Assert
  location: class MenusTest
Error:(33, 9) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable Assert
  location: class MenusTest
```

Comment: ты думаешь, кто-то будет разбираться в твоем скрине? код нужно сюда скинуть и подкрепить скрином ошибок

Comment: Сейчас добавлю код,но по скрину проще.

Answer (score 0):

**Решение : Нужно вынести папку Tests с тестируемыми классами из папки** ***src*** просто в папку ***out***